# oracle database, error in adding datafiles to an existing tablespace

Tags: database, oracle

I want to add datafiles to an existing tablespace. The command I am using is:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE "HIGH_VOLUME"
ADD DATAFILE '/data2/oracle/oradata/CMGPERF02/hv05.dbf'
SIZE 30G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M LOGGING DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS ONLINE EXTENT 
MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
```

error:

> Error starting at line : 28 in command - ALTER TABLESPACE
>   "HIGH_VOLUME" ADD DATAFILE '/data2/oracle/oradata/CMGPERF02/hv05.dbf'
>   SIZE 30G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M LOGGING DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS ONLINE
>   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
>   Error report - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

I have sysdba access , so it might not be an access related issue i guess. Even I searched in oracle docs site and writen answer is.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE lmtbsb
ADD DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/data/lmtbsb02.dbf' SIZE 1M;
```

there might be syntax error from my end. kindly help me to rectify it. Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs are pretty confusing to read](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3002.htm#SQLRF01002), but basically you're combining **tablespace-level options** (like logging and compression) with an `ADD DATAFILE` clause, which doesn't work. [The only options](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses004.htm#CJADEBBF) which can follow `ADD DATAFILE` are SIZE, REUSE, and AUTOEXTEND. If you want to alter tablespace options, use a separate `ALTER TABLESPACE` command.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE "HIGH_VOLUME" 
ADD DATAFILE '/data2/oracle/oradata/CMGPERF02/hv05.dbf' 
SIZE 30G 
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M
-- These are tablespace options which can't be applied to single datafiles: 
--LOGGING 
--DEFAULT 
--NOCOMPRESS 
--ONLINE 
--EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE 
--SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
```